# Trying to do threads in android using subclass runnable

Tags: android

I'm using android studio to do my codding.
I have a class that implements the Runnable class.  Android studio is saying the start method for my runable class is undefined.  Is this done different in android then regular java?

Runnable class:

```
public class cThreadRandomTime implements Runnable {

    int ted=0;

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch( Exception e) {
            ted++;
        }
    }
}
```

Test method:

```
void test2() {
    cThreadRandomTime mThreadRandomTime = new cThreadRandomTime();
    // start is displayed in red     
    mThreadRandomTime.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are instructions for one way how you would run a thread.

1.create a class that implements Runnable (which you did)

2.Instantiate a thread object & pass it a Runnable object)

3.call .start() on the thread

```
//create a runnable object
cThreadRandomTime mThreadRandomTime = new cThreadRandomTime();
//instantiate a thread object & pass it a runnable object
Thread myThread = new Thread(mThreadRandomTime);
//start the thread
myThread.start();
```

There are two ways to create a thread.

1.One way is to create a class that extends Thread

2.create a class that implements Runnable (you did this)

This is how you create the thread class using the first way.(extends Thread)

```
class ExampleThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do work....
        }
}
```

This is how you run a thread using the first method (notice you don't have to pass it a runnable object this time)

```
Thread myThread = new ExampleThread();
myThread.start();
```

So you mixed it up a bit, you implemented runnable and tried to run a Runnable object, Instead you should try to run a Thread object and pass it a Runnable object.

The runnable object is considered the task or work you need done.

The thread is what the task/work will run on.

It highlighted start() in red because .start() doesn't exist on the Runnable object, it exists in the thread object.